# Rails 5 Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I am using web-socket in my rails application:
with Rails 5.2.3, ruby 2.4.0p0, my websocket is working find over http but having following error when I switch to https.
The error is as:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://tukaweb.com/cable' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

I have tried changing the configuration in production.rb to

```
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://tukaweb.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://tukaweb.com', /http:\/\/tukaweb.*/ ]
```

and

```
  config.action_cable.url = [/ws:\/\/*/, /wss:\/\/*/]
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
```

also added action cable meta tag:

```
 <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
```

But the error still persists, can anybody suggest the correct configuration, thanks and why its working find over http test bed environment but giving error on https with ssl.
also I am using Nginx server with passenger module to run rails environment.

Answer (score 1):

updated the /home/vidur/Downloads/tukaweb/app/assets/javascripts/cable.js to:

```
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable =  ActionCable.createConsumer("/cable");

}).call(this);
```

Production.rb to:

```
  config.action_cable.url = "/cable"
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://52.35.24.20','http://tukaweb.com', 'https://tukaweb.com' ]
```

routes.rb to:

```
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

cable.yml to:

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

updated the virtualhost to:

```
location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name tukaweb_action_cable;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer or an update to your question?

Comment: this is the answer, which resolve the 502 handshake error.

Comment: Do you know exact cause of the issue was? In that case consider updating your answer with the cause and mark it as the correct answer.